# Weird behaviour after calling execv

Tags: c, linux, execv

I am trying to execute a command using execv. After running this program, I can see the statement "Going to call execv!" being printed on the standard output.

I can also see the prints from the program "leaky". Actually everything is working as expected except that I can't see print statements in the if or else block i.e. neither "execv failed! error: " nor "Successfully executed valgrind!" is being printed on the output.

Am I missing some obvious point here about execv?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
   char *args[5] = {"/usr/bin/valgrind", "--leak-check=full", "--log-file=valgrindReport.txt", "./leaky", NULL};
   printf("Going to call execv!\n");
   if(execv("/usr/bin/valgrind", args) < 0)
   {
      printf("execv failed! error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Successfully executed valgrind!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) will help you: "The exec() family of functions **replaces** the current process image" and "The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred."

Comment: If `execv` succeeds in running the program, the caller process is kind of "replaced" by the new program. So it's not "call program and get result", use `system` function for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the C execv() function terminate the child proccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172257/does-the-c-execv-function-terminate-the-child-proccess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get the output of valgrind then obviously `execve` was successful. If `execve` is successful it replaces the current process image with the one to be started and does not return. If `execve` returns then it failed.